# Microsoft Surface Headphones 2 - mic button with sensitivity issue on Mac OS x

Tags: macos, headphones, microsoft-surface, remapping

I just bought a Microsoft Surface Headphones 2 and I'm using it with multiple devices. My main computer is running Mac OS X.

The headphones are really great, the problem is, when I press the mute button it works really good, however, when I press it again, it just put the mic sensitivity to the maximum when I was using like 20%.

When I'm using the headphones on Zoom and I take it from my head, it just put mute automatically, when I put it again, it just automatically put the mic sensibility to 100%.

There is any way to limit the mic sensitivity using the terminal or remap?

Comment: sensibility = sensitivity?

Comment: Yes, sorry about my mistake.