# Script for Automator on Mac OS X to limit MacBook mic sensitivity

Tags: macos, script, automator

It is possible to use Automator from Mac OS X to limit the maximum sensitivity of the microphone of the computer?

For example, if my headphone change it automatically to 100% it automatically put the sensitivity of the mic to 20%.

Comment: This is basically a dupe of your other question posted at the exact same time: https://superuser.com/questions/1634074/microsoft-surface-headphones-2-mic-button-with-sensitivity-issue-on-mac-os-x

Comment: Is not the same question. One is about hardware and this one is about software. And no one answered me, is not that simple... So could you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's possible for Automator to control the mic input level:
[image: automator]

You could bind it to a shortcut key (Google for "Quick Actions" and Services and shortcut keys, there are lots of examples online), or you could run in a permanent loop (might use a lot of CPU though), or see if there's some way to trigger it on the headphones being plugged in (but I haven't heard of that).